# Mocking DynamoDB BatchWrite using Jest

Tags: javascript, docker, jestjs, amazon-dynamodb

Can you please give me a hand here? ;)

So, I'm using Jest to mock the calls to DynamoDB, using a local Docker DynamoDB image.

Detailing:

The class A, calls the following method:

```
const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: "us-east-1" });
await upsertItems(dynamoDB, items, existingItems);
```

This calls Class B, where:

```
await dynamoDB.batchWrite({
            RequestItems: {
                [TABLE_NAME]: requestItems.splice(0, maxBatch),
            }
        }).promise();
```

What I'm trying to achieve is change the dynamoDB target, so that it uses a local Docker instance rather than the one the is passed in class A

I tried the following Jest mock:

```
AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.prototype.batchWrite = jest.fn().mockImplementation(async (params) => {

const dbClient = new DynamoDBClient({ region: "us-west-2", endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000' });

    const { Item } = await params.RequestItems.undefined[0].PutRequest

    const putParams = {
        TableName: 'table_name',
        Item: {
            "PK": {S: Item.PK},
            "SK": {S: Item.SK},
            "data": {S: JSON.stringify(Item.data)},
            "type": {S: Item.type},
        }
    };

    const putCommand = new PutItemCommand(putParams)

    try {
        const results = await dbClient.send(putCommand);
        console.log('statusCode: ', results.$metadata.httpStatusCode);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
})
```

The idea would be mocking the implementation of the BatchWrite function, to use instead the Put, into the Docker's DynamoDB, but when I reach the `dbClient.send(putCommand);`, I'm getting a `TypeError: dynamoDB.batchWrite(...).promise is not a function`.

I tried this to mock the function .promise():

```
AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.prototype.batchWrite = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    promise: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(() => Promise.resolve()),
});
```

And it worked a few times, but now the `mockImplementation` is not being used and only the `Promise.resolve()` is called by the B class

Can you guys give me a hand, as I'm new to Jest mocking?